# AsyncTreeNode in Extjs 4 migrating from 3 to 4

Tags: extjs4

Does declaring root:{ nodeType: 'async'} serve the purpose of AsyncTreeNode in Ext 3 ?

If yes, how can I test it?
If no, what can be done to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

> **nodeType** doesn't do anything anymore so you can remove that. By
>   defining a store with a proxy all nodes become asynchronous unless you
>   set children to an empty array in which case it won't make a request
>   when you expand the node.

For more info: **http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?128137-Where-is-AsyncTreeNode**